# Does Plane Shift enable teleporting to a different location on the same plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes, teleportation

Say a caster wants to travel to a different continent on the same plane. Can that journey be made using the spell [*plane shift*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plane-shift), or can *plane shift* be used only to travel to a different plane than the caster's currently on?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is specifically answered in the spell’s description:

> You and up to eight willing creatures who link hands in a circle are transported to a **different** plane of existence.

Nowhere does it say you can teleport to a location on the same plane of existence, so you can’t.

The caveat being that in order to travel to a different location on your starting plane of existence you would need to cast Plane Shift twice, which typically requires a long rest between castings, a 15th level caster sacrificing their only 7th and 8th level spell slots, 2 casters of the appropriate level, or some other way to cast a 7th level spell twice per day. This will allow you to a different plane on the first casting then a different location back on your original plane on the second casting.

Comment: While this is of course correct, it's noteworthy that using *plane shift* **twice** will actually allow you to teleport to a different place on your starting plane.

Comment: @Miniman That also takes, typically, two days... since standard you only get 1 7th spell slot per long rest any more.

Comment: @Slagmoth Depending on the distance traveled and a lack of Teleporation circle (Knowing the spell, not knowing the location cause you'll need that if you want a specific location) It might be better using Planeshift twice than traveling in a mundane way.

Comment: You might want to modify your caveat paragraph to indicate 15th level, not 17th. Nothing prevents a caster from using their 8th level slot to cast a 7th level spell unless they're a warlock.